# I would like to have the difference between 2 files. Want to find specifically at what column the difference has occured using Unix Scripting

Tags: perl, shell, unix, solaris, nawk

We are doing a data migration project migrating from Informix to Oracle. Now a requirement has come up to compare the data between Informix and oracle tables. So Table1 from Informix will be migrated to Table1 in Oracle.
Now data is migrated from `Table1` in Informix to `Table1` in Oracle. I am taking data from both the tables into 2 flat files.I want to just see if there is any data difference in 2 files.

`File1` has say 1 million records with 300 columns and `File2` say 1 million records with 300 columns. `File1` and `File2` are pipe delimited files. So difference can be anywhere in the file. Almost a whole row can match, but there can be difference in one/two columns. So I would like to find out the differences, keeping all the above things in mind. Difference output should list out something like `row1 in file1 is not matching with row1 in file2 at column 3` and the value of the columns from both files. All such differences from both the files need to be listed out on the console with layman understandable format.

I want to just explain it with an example to make it more clear.

My first file if it looks like below:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6
1234|ramyakrishna|4567|ramya.krishna@worse.com|228802|worse
1235|Chandan|4567|chandan.kumar@worse.com|228862|worse
1236|Kacitha|4567|kacitha.mishra@worse.com|228872|worse
1238|Shajin|4567|shajin.mahesh@worse.com|228873|worse
```

My second file looks like this:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6
1234|ramyakrishna|4567|ramya.krishna@good.com|228802|good
1235|Chandan|4567|chandan.kumar@worse.com|228789|worse
1236|Kacitha|4567|kacitha.mishra@worse.com|228872|worse
```

So when i compare both the files. We see that there is a difference in `col4` and `col6` in `row2`. So I want something like this:

```
1234|ramyakrishna|4567|ramya.krishna@good.com|228802|good
:COL4-EXPECTED-ramya.krishna@worse.com:COL6-EXPECTED-worse
```

So in above row from second file should be printed. Then expected values should be printed.

I know files need to be sorted before using any script.

---

For fge's script i am getting ouput like below:

I am getting ouput like below

```
$perl diff.perl    

Line 1: different value for column 38 (was g, expected w)
Line 1: different value for column 40 (was o, expected r)
Line 1: different value for column 41 (was d, expected s)
Line 1: different value for column 42 (was ., expected e)
Line 1: different value for column 43 (was c, expected .)
Line 1: different value for column 44 (was o, expected c)
Line 1: different value for column 45 (was m, expected o)
Line 1: different value for column 46 (was |, expected m)
```

I want whole column comparison. Files are `|` delimited files.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the files are sorted in the same order, look at `comm` or `diff`.  Be advised that this operates on the line-level.  To drill down to differences at the field level you might begin with the subset population of those differing a the line-level.

Comment: Yeah I tried using comm but i ended up in just listing out rows which have differences. But could not list where exactly 2 rows differ.Thanks for the Answer.

Comment: I tried using comm command. Here how can i  get the records just unique to file1 and unique to file2. I am not interested in the records common to both the files. So once we have records unique to each other then probably we can look for some work around to check for exact difference.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (in perl) may do -- it assumes that the files have the same number of lines, but this can be easily checked with `wc`, and that no line is empty:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W
use strict;

open FILE1, "file1" or die;
open FILE2, "file2" or die;

my (@cols1, @cols2);
my ($val1, $val2);
my $linenr = 0;

while (my $line = <FILE1>) {
    @cols1 = split('|', $line);
    @cols2 = split('|', <FILE2>);
    $linenr++;

    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#cols1; $i++) {
        $val1 = $cols1[$i]; $val2 = $cols2[$i];
        if ("$val1" ne "$val2") {
            printf("Line %d: different value for column %d (was %s, expected %s)\n",
                $linenr, $i+1, $val2, $val1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `#!/usr/bin/perl -W`, instead of just `use warnings;`?

Comment: `if( "$val1" != "$val2" ){...}` is probably wrong. Use `if( $val1 ne $val2 ){...}` instead. ( Or `if( $val1 != $val2 ){...}` if you really do want to compare numerically. )

Comment: @BradGilbert yeah, I'm not doing too much perl anymore :/

Comment: I figured since forcing a value to a string to compare it string-wise is something other languages require. ( if you do want to get into the swing of things, read [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html). Available as a PDF for free. )

Comment: @fge: I tried using your script after doing changes suggested by  Brad Gilbert. But script is doing character by character comparison and not field comparison. I have updated my question with an example. Hope it helps you in helping me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually have the column headers at the start of your file? Also, you say files need to be sorted - by what? Do you have space for a copy of the files?

Comment: Yeah I have the column headers at the start of my files.Sorting i just presumed is required since in your script you are trying to do comparison row by row. Usually if we sort both the files and then do comparison then it works out?.. I have just given the extreme case as 1 million records in the file. But it can vary from few thousands to lakhs...Hmm copying of files should not be a problem.. But only aiming to  get the desired results..

Comment: Well, provided you remove column headers AND sort (let's say by the first column which is a number) than it should work, yes. To generate these temporary files, you could `sed 1d|sort -n origfile >dstfile` for both and then run the script. With a little more work, it could handle column headers as well.

Comment: I tried but ur script is trying to compare character by character rather column by column or row by row. Can you please have a look into that?..

Comment: Well, I thought you wanted column compare... If you mean to compare only rows, then it's much more simple

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6432/discussion-between-chkusi-and-fge)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to compare two big files because its fast. Unfortunately, its only available in Windows (will be available in linux soon).

Since your flat files are coming from the database, you can easily sort it when you dump the tables. Then use winmerge to compare the files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately our system run on Solaris machine and we have to use some Unix work around to do this.